# Gitlab docker backup and restore

Tags: docker, gitlab, backup, restore

I am using GitLab via docker on an intranet disconnected from the internet.
I run GitLab docker using docker-compose following yml file.

```
web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: 'myowngit.com'
    ports:
        - 8880:80
        - 8443:443
    volumes:
        - /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
        - /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
        - /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
```

Then free space of 'volumes' is not enough so i move this path to '/mnt/mydata'.
And I modify docker-compose.yml file.

```
... ... ...
    volumes:
        - /mnt/mydata/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
        - /mnt/mydata/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
        - /mnt/mydata/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab
```

To start GitLab service run `sudo docker-compose up -d`.
After running the GitLab service I try to explore the project repository but the repository is not found(HTTP response 404 or 503).
What is the reason?
How to move GitLab docker volume directory?

Answer (score 1):

It should work unless, as shown in [docker-gitlab issue 562](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-gitlab/issues/562), to move was done with a different ownership

> It should be okay to move the files from `/data1/data` to `/data2/data`, you should take a little care while copying the files to the new location. i.e. either of these should be fine
>
> ```
> cp -a /data1/data /data2/data
> rsync --progress -av /data1/data /data2/data
> ```
>
> Simply doing `cp -r /data1/data /data2/data` will not preserve the ownership of the files which will cause issues.